# Using SSPI (NTLM) Api's With Windows AccessCheck() On Vista With UAC

Tags: windows-vista, uac, sspi

Summary 
Client (Windows XP SP3) 
Server (Windows Vista Business SP1) / Running as LocalSystem Service

Api Sequence 
Client - AcquireCredentialsHandle 
Client - Initializesecuritycontext 
Server - Acquirecredentialshandle 
Server - AcceptSecurityContext 
Client/Server - CompleteAuthnToken 
Server - ImpersonateSecurityContext 
Server - AccessCheckAndAuditAlarm (MAXIMUM_allowed) 
Server - I then compare the access requested with the allowed accesses.

I call access check against a private security object created with createprivateobjectsecurityex. With Uac turned on I get success back from accesscheck, but none of the privledges are held. With uac turned off I get success back with all of the rights in the GantedAccess parameter

Details 
The application has two componets to it, a client and a server. It 
uses tcp to communicat over an unsecured network. To authentication 
the incomming connections I use the sspi api's listed above, and 
impersonate the calling user. Once the calling user is impersonated I 
use Accesscheckandauditalarm, if this fails the i revert back to just 
accesscheck. With UAC turned on I am getting success back from 
accesscheckandauditalarm but none of the access rights are in the 
grandedaccess paramter, but if uac is turned off it works as expected. 
I have check the integrity level of the server process and it is set 
to High, I have looked the integrity level of the impersonation token 
used to impersonate the calling user and it is set to Medium. I have 
tried setting the integrity level of the calling user to high, with 
success but the access check still returns incorrrect results. 
THinking I might have a linked token I tried the linked token with a 
call to GetTOkenInformation(TokenLInkedToken) with a result of 0x520. 
Any thoughts on what I might try next would be appreciated.

Code after authentication.

```
SECURITY_STATUS ss = SEC_E_OK; 
 HANDLE _hToken = NULL; 
 ss = QuerySecurityContextToken((PCtxtHandle)pContext,&_hToken); 
 if(SEC_E_OK != ss) 
 { 
  return ss; 
 } 
 CAccessToken impToken; 
 impToken.Attach(_hToken); 
 if(CWin32::IsVista()) 
 { 
  /*TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN linkedToken; 
  DWORD nLen = 0; 
  BOOL bRet = GetTokenInformation(_hToken, 
(TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS)TokenLinkedToken,&linkedToken,sizeof(linkedToken), &nLen); 
  if(bRet) 
  { 
   CloseHandle(impToken.Detach()); 
   impToken.Attach(linkedToken.LinkedToken); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
   TRACE(_T("GetTokenInfo Failed 0x%x\n"),GetLastError()); 
  }*/ 
  PSID    pHighIntegritySid = NULL; 
  BOOL bConvertSid = FALSE; 
  bConvertSid = ConvertStringSidToSid(SDDL_ML_HIGH, 
&pHighIntegritySid); 
  if (bConvertSid) 
  { 
   TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL TML = {0}; 
   TML.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY | 
SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY_ENABLED; 
   TML.Label.Sid        = pHighIntegritySid; 
   BOOL bSetTokenRet = SetTokenInformation(_hToken, 
(TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS)TokenIntegrityLevel,&TML,sizeof(TML) + 
GetLengthSid(pHighIntegritySid)); 
   LocalFree(pHighIntegritySid); 
   if(!bSetTokenRet) 
   { 
    nReturn = GetLastError(); 
    DBGOUT(DebugOut::LOG_COMP_AUTH_LAYER,DebugOut::LOG_DETAIL_ERROR, 
     _T("Failed to set Token information %x\n"),nReturn); 
    return nReturn; 
   } 
  } 
 } 
 bool bRet = impToken.Impersonate(); 
 if(false == bRet) 
 { 
  return GetLastError(); 
 } 
 _GetTokenSecurityLevel(impToken.GetHandle()); 
 ::MapGenericMask(&nRights, GetGENERIC_MAPPING()); 
 DWORD nAccessGranted = 0; 
 BOOL bAccessStatus = FALSE; 
 BOOL bGenerateOnClose = FALSE; 
 BOOL bAccessCheckRet = FALSE; 
 bAccessCheckRet = ::AccessCheckAndAuditAlarm(_T("Purgos 
Security"),impToken.GetHandle(),_T("Purgos"),m_csObjectName.GetBuffer(0), 
const_cast<SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR*>(m_ObjectSD.GetPSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR())/ 
*privObjectSD.GetPSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR())*/,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,GetGENERIC_MAPPI NG(),FALSE,&nAccessGranted,&bAccessStatus,&bGenerateOnClose);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the Solution to all interested parties.

The problem was that the user being authenticated was a local account, and by default local accounts have a filtered token with the BUILTIN\Administrators group having a deny ACL. And I was checking rights against the BUILTIN\Administrators group. So had to set a registry setting or use a domain account.

Ryan